# What are those items hanging behind the shop keeper?

Tags: props, no-country-for-old-men

In *No Country for Old Men*, Anton offers a coin toss to a shop keeper.

[image]

There is a row of cable-tie looking items hanging behind the shop keeper. What are they? I have never seen them in a gas station? Must be specific of that time, 1980s or that region.

Comment: They could be driving belts, but you should ask someone who knows more about cars, rather than movies.

Comment: @TK-421, thanks. But when I came up with this question, I did not know they were related to cars.

Comment: Anton has stopped at a gas station / convenience store / automobile service station. He has gone in to pay for filling up his car with fuel. He wants to remain anonymous as he travels in a stolen car. Not to mention, he has probably killed the car’s owner to acquire it. As an automotive shop, it would carry and sell products related to cars. Especially products that require constant and frequent service (oil, coolant, drive belts, etc). It would also carry products of convenience for people on roadtrips. They were, and still are, quite common on US state and federal highways.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They are engine accessory drive belts. They are attached between the engine crank shaft and the engine components like:

- Water pump
- Alternator
- Air conditioning compressor
- Power steering pump (in some cases)
- Cooling fan (when not electric)
- Superchargers
- Etc.

Most of these separate belts were replaced by one longer drive belt called the serpentine belt. It was attached between all or most of the components listed as well as various pulleys to provide mechanical power from the engine to run them.

Prior to 1990, the belts shown were pretty ubiquitous to every car. And, like any other part, were prone to wear.  Checking and replacing them was a common point of regular maintenance. More common than changing tires since your average driver could do it themselves. Almost as common as checking the oil.

These types of belts were thinner than the more robust serpentine belts. The serpentine belt in a shop would look very much like a thicker version of the belts shown. Just doubled up in the package due to their length. Some of the belts in this shot may be early serpentine belts. Their thickness would be the determine factor versus a pack of two, thinner, drive belts.

Even into the beginning of the twenty-first century, cars with regular drive belts would have been plentiful on the American road as daily drivers. Now, they are more of a Collectors item. But, even as late as 2010, I would change my own serpentine belts and tensioner pulleys.

Comment: "Engine accessory drive belts" known to common people as "fan belts."

Comment: Oh my. As a 60+ year old man, I rolled my eyes at this question hard enough that it hurt. Then I realized that not only do kids no longer work on cars, in general, neither do their parents....

Comment: @CGCampbell - In all fairness, this is now a disposable economy. I have had the pleasure of owning cars from 7 different decades. I unusually own 3 to 4 cars at a time. And, I keep my cars for an average of 15 years each. This is not the case for most people. They would rather buy the newest car and get rid of it before it reaches a point to where they have to work on it. Going from one car note to another.

Comment: @CGCampbell my car is 13 years old and the water pump is electrical and has no belt, the cooling fans are also electrical, but there is a serpentine belt for the aircon and power steering

Comment: Another term I've seen for these is "V belts", referring to the cross sectional shape of the belt.

Comment: @RichieFrame - A lot of cars of your era have electric coolant/water pumps. Especially German cars with aluminum engines like BMW. Probably to protect the aluminum engine (since it is so heat sensitive) by sensing coolant flow. Then, putting the car in limp mode if there is not enough flow volume or pressure. They will still have a belt for the alternator. Although, an aluminum Rotax engine still has a mechanical water pump.

Comment: @DeanF. the serpentine belt does run the alternator as well. the main reason it is electric is for performance, to keep flow high during idle, and slow it down when you are at highway cruise speed, or speed it up when you stomp the throttle but before the engine heat soaks into the coolant

Comment: @RichieFrame - My point exactly. The alternator is still run by the serpentine belt, not just the AC. But, your reason for an electric water pump on a high performance, aluminum engine makes sense.

Comment: And modern dealers actually **discourage** outright ownership of new cars. Dealers would rather you lease cars for the rest of your life than sell you a new car. If you want to buy it, they also discourage paying full price. Always with financing and whatever. If you walk into a dealer with cash, and want to pay it off right away, some people won't want to deal with you.

Comment: Looking at the IMCDb.org entry for this movie, all of the cars and trucks used (except possibly the MCI, which I'd never heard of) use belts such as shown. Most are 70's Chevy's and Fords. Once I'd figured out the MCI is a bus, well, it uses them too.

Comment: @CGCampbell Me too, and I'm only mid-40s.  That said, I do get my car serviced at a garage these days, but only because I can better afford the money than the time.

Comment: @DeanF. Re drive belts wearing out, it's probably relevant to say that the improved lifespan of synthetic rubber parts is the reason for this.  Back in the day, the chemical stability of rubber drive belts in a harsh environment was low, so 1-2 years was all you could get out of them before the plasticisers failed.  It wasn't until the mid-late 80s that rubber timing belts appeared, and they were *expensive*.  It was some time after that before the rubber got robust enough for accessory belts to not be a disposable change-every-service item.

Comment: FWIW, a serpentine belt: https://thehappycar.com/wp-content/uploads/serpentine-belt-2.jpg

Comment: Isn't the water pump usually driven by the timing belt (or timing chain)?  The rest of the items listed would be driven by a serpentine belt or fan belts.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - It depends on the car. But, for the most part, no. The water pump is usually a replaceable item on the exterior of the engine that can be accessed without getting into the crankcase or engine housing (currently at a loss for the proper term) itself. The electric water pump mentioned earlier is a plastic (on the outside) part bolted to the exterior of the engine. At least on the BMW it is. They are situated between the hoses from the radiator and the engine block, attached to the engine block itself. The timing belt is inside the engine housing where you can not see it.

Comment: Just to add, these could be drive belts for ride-on lawnmowers, drive belts for workshop drill presses, or drive belts for a plethora of other pulley-driven machines. Being a fuel station it's most likely that they're engine v-belts.

Comment: @CGCampbell 58 hours of Car Mechanic Simulator 2018 did teach me some things about cars, and it was a lot cleaner than that one time I changed my own oil.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqMdQBox15s). There are frames that are more zoomed out, such as 4:24. At 0:47, you can see that they're labelled with the number 15540. When I googled that number, the third result was [this](https://www.autozone.com/cooling-heating-and-climate-control/belt/duralast-v-belt-belt-15440/304022_0_0). Other than the first two results, all of the results on the first page seem to be fan belts. Also, at 0:05, you can see this is a gas station, which suggests that they may be automotive supplies.